# how to implement Spring Security SpEL isFullyAuthenticated() programmatically in a controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a controller where I would like to check if a user in Fully Authenticated similar to what Spring Security `isFullyAuthenticated()` expression provides. How do I do that?

Solution I am using based on Tomasz Nurkiewicz answer below and just stealing the implementation from org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot

```
 public class SpringSecurityUtils {
    private static final AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    public static boolean isFullyAuthenticated()
    {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return !trustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) && !trustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [`SecurityExpressionRoot`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html) and [`AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl.html) looks like you can use the following condition:

```
public boolean isFullyAuthenticated(Authentication auth) {
    return !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken || 
             auth instanceof RememberMeAuthenticationToken);
}
```

Where you obtain authentication e.g. using:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [`isUserInRole()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29) method of `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` or the `HttpServletRequest` using the string [`IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AuthenticatedVoter.html#IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY):

```
request.isUserInRole("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY");
```

Comment: This isn't actually true. `isUserInRole()` only checks the supplied string against the `Authentication` object's authority list. `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` is an attribute consumed by the `AuthenticatedVoter` which is a different thing.

Comment: @Luke I really hope SpringSecurity will add some public API to do the equivalent of the Spring Security SPEL exppressions! I am happy to add a request to JIRA if you guys don't have one already :)